# Regression line - R Summary(lm...)) calculates the estimate & slope( beta0 & beta1) of what?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, lm

Hi I have a question concerning R, statistics, regression and Summary(lm(....))

When using R and the summary(lm(..)) function I get an output like that:

[image]

I pretty much know what each of the numbers means but it is not clear for me what the estimate and std Error are calculated from.

When I plot a plot like that

[image]

I have 32 (x/y)-Datapoints. Now I fit a linear model and get a beta0 as well as an beta1. **What exactly are beta0 and beta1 calculated from ?**

- the residuals ? ( do I get 32 *distances* from where I calculate the estimate+ StdError ?)
- the slope ? ( do I get the first point, fit a line through this point-> get one beta1, take the second point and fit a line through these 2 pts -> get another beta1,...  Then I take the Estimate + StdError of 32 *beta1`s* ?)

Comment: It sounds like you need some basic background information. I would start [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-simple-linear-regression/), [here](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/linear-models-r-plotting-regression-lines/), [here](https://feliperego.github.io/blog/2015/10/23/Interpreting-Model-Output-In-R), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation). The first three are clearly written, beginner-level pieces on understanding output from R's `lm()` and plotting, while the last one is the Wikipedia on how you estimate OLS coefficients.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't really asking a programming question as much as a statistics question.  I think you just need to read up on how to fit a multiple linear regression.